# How shall I properly address the pipe?

Tags: r, magrittr

Trying to make `magrittr pinping` function more graceful and readable. However, the best I can do about this is as following. How can I improve it? Please find the referential code, and advise. **Thanks**

`DF <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=1L:10L, c=1.01:1.10, d=rep(TRUE,10), e=10L:1L)`

```
cols <- lapply(DF,class) %>% unlist()
cols[which(cols %in% c("integer","numeric"))]

#        b         c         e 
#"integer" "numeric" "integer"
#
# yet, I'd still like to get rid of the variables.
```

the best I can do in piping is like this. Tried with `%$%`, but failed.

```
(lapply(DF,class) %>% unlist)[
which(lapply(DF,class) %>% unlist() =="integer" |
      lapply(DF,class) %>% unlist() =="numeric")]
```

can I make it something like this?

```
lapply(DF,class) %>% unlist %$% .[which(. %in% c("integer","numeric"))]
# of course, it doesn't work
```

Comment: that code won't work if you have any multiclass columns (e.g. `c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')`

Comment: yes, I dropped in that hole, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `Filter` from `base R` to remove those columns with class `integer` or `numeric`

```
Filter(function(x) !class(x) %in% c("integer", "numeric"), DF)
```

For keeping those variables

```
Filter(function(x) class(x) %in% c("integer", "numeric"), DF)
```

---

Or using the `%>%`, get the `class` of the columns with `map`, check whether it is `%in%`, 'integer' or 'numeric', negate (`!` - only if we need to remove those variables) and `magrittr::extract` the columns based on the logical index

```
library(tidyverse)
map_chr(DF, class) %>% 
    `%in%`(c("integer", "numeric")) %>% 
    #`!` %>%  #in case to remove those columns
    extract(DF, .)
```

Or with `discard` to remove the columns

```
discard(DF, ~class(.x) %in% c("integer", "numeric"))
```

or `keep` to keep the columns

```
keep(DF, ~ class(.x) %in% c("integer", "numeric"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun I think you r saying `Filter(function(x) class(x) %in% c("integer", "numeric"), DF)'. it does work, now I will go further on `POSIXct` and see it works. Thanks, sir, U r truly a respectful mentor.

Comment: @Grec001  Do you want to remove those columns or keep it?

Comment: I wanna find them, and work on them. So you gave a perfect answer if I remove the `!`. The Filter way is smart.

Comment: @Grec001 In that case, just remove the `!` in the pipe in the `Filter`

Comment: you should use inherits, not class

Comment: @MichaelChirico I tried `inherits(DF, c("integer", "numeric", "POSIXct"), TRUE)`, and it gave no result. Would you mind sharing? That would be great!

Comment: @Grec001 don't use `exact = TRUE` -- compare `inherits(1L, c('numeric', 'integer', 'POSIXct'), TRUE)` and `inherits(1L, c('numeric', 'integer', 'POSIXct'))`